# Specifying a type as being some string literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I wanted to create a function `assignKey` that is similar to `Object.assign()`, but instead of taking objects to merge together, it takes a starting object, a key, and a value. It returns a new object based on the original object with the argument key and value added in.

Implementing this behavior is trivial. In plain JS, it would look like:

```
function assignKey(obj, key, value) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {[key]: value});
}
```

However, I'm having real trouble when it comes to keeping it as strongly typed as possible.

If I run `assignKey({}, 'foo', 'bar')`, I would like the result to be typed as `{ foo: string }`.

If I run `assignKey({}, Math.random().toString(), 'bar')` I would expect the result to be typed as `{[x: string]: string}`

If you do the corresponding operations with regular `Object.assign()` you do end up with these results. So:

- `Object.assign({}, { 'foo': 'bar' })` gives the type `{ 'foo': string }`
- `Object.assign({}, { [Math.random().toString()]: 'bar' })` gives the type `{[x: string]: string}`

Typing `obj` and `value` is simple:

```
function assignKey<O, V>(obj: O, key, value: V)
```

But I'm having real trouble giving a type to `key` such that it keeps the typing accurate.

If I type it as `string` then I lose granularity when it is in fact a string literal. I was hoping that typing it as `K extends string` and `key: K` might be able to represent the fact that it could either be a string literal or a string, but this does not seem so.

And so my question is, **is there any way I could type `key` as being either some string literal or just of type `string` such that the resulting output can be as accurately typed as possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much do what you want:

```
function assignKey<T, K extends string, V>(obj: T, key: K, value: V ): T & Record<K, V> {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {[key]: value} as Record<K,V>);
}
```

Here the key is type `K extends string`, which is all you need to get TypeScript to infer a literal if necessary.  The value is type `V`, and the returned type is an intersection with [`Record<K,V>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.1/lib/lib.d.ts#L1350), a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) from the standard library, where the keys are of type `K` and the values are of type `V`.  Then you get:

```
const example1: {foo: string} = assignKey({}, 'foo', 'bar'); 
// Record<"foo",string>

const example2: {[k: string]: string} = assignKey({}, Math.random().toString(), 'bar')
// Record<string, string>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I thought about somehow using a mapped type in the return type declaration but didn't consider the need/ability to also use `as` internally for the `assign` call. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I guess TypeScript (at least as of v2.6) doesn't understand `{[key]: value}` to be type `Record<K,V>`; so you have to tell it.